# Ok No restart after 20.04 upgrade/install

Tags: restart

No issues prior to install. X200 ThinkPad. No restart at end of install. Will start normally from power off. Restart hangs on ThinkPad logo. New to Linux and struggling to find a solution I can comprehend.

Message prior to ThinkPad logo indicates failure and files not found (something to that effect). Message flashes so fast I can't copy/read it fully.

I tried Boot-Repair but I get an error indicating to disable the Legacy in BIOS. Fearful of creating a bigger problem. I do plan to Libreboot this PC and waiting on a clip.

Thanks for any input.

Bill

Answer (score 2):

Solved. I reinstalled 18.04. Runs perfect. Apparently 20.04 isn't quite ready for prime time. I have a T450s arriving tomorrow, maybe I'll have more luck with it. Fingers crossed.